# The form of the residual vector in the multiple linear regression model

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, prediction, residuals

I have 2 questions about multiple linear regression model.

Does the residual vector in the multiple linear regression model have the form $y-(X(X^T X)^{-1}  X^T)^2 y$?

And, is it true that the sample distribution for a linear combination of model parameters in the
multiple linear regression model is used in deriving the prediction interval for a future observation $x_0$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the residual vector is correct but the expression can be simplified because: $$(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^2y=X(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-1}Xy=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty=X\hat{\beta}=\hat{y}$$
and residuals are $r=y-\hat{y}$. You don't have to square the term in the parentheses.

Since $\hat y_0=\hat{\beta}x_0$, prediction interval will use sampling distribution of parameter estimates.

Comment: oh thank you so much, that was really helpful...can i do one more question? Is it true or false that the sample distribution for a linear combination of model parameters in the multiple linear regression model is used in deriving the prediction interval for a future observation x0?

Comment: yes, i tried to address that question in my last sentence.

Comment: it's a different question..idk whether its true or false

Comment: I still don't realize the difference, but ok it's true.

Comment: what explanation i can write to justify that it is true that  the sample distribution for a linear combination of model parameters in the multiple linear regression model is used in deriving the prediction interval for a future observation x0?

Comment: Because y0 depends on model parameter estimations; the with the equation I gave in the answer (last sentence).

Comment: okay thank you so much! can you check out and the question i wrote now? i really need help for that one! thank you again

Comment: your question in the comment is the same as the question in the original post. My answer for that question is both in my post and comments.

Comment: no, i mean the question i have posted after this question.. not this in the comment..

Comment: yeah of course..

Comment: yes that is what i mean..can you help me with that please?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote; do you know how to accept an answer? You'll click the "tick" sign under the arrows upper left.

Comment: You are welcome! can you help me with the other question?

Comment: It appears that the answer is ok for your but you haven't accepted it yet, do you know how to accept it? I've described it in my previous comment. For the other question, it's not completely appropriate for us to discuss that here in another thread because this is a community forum and people might wonder what you're referring to. This post with its question and answer is self-contained and should stay so. I'll try to look at your other post and answer/give hints if I'm *able*.

Comment: ok i have done it...can you answer and help me to the other post that i am talking about? thank you

Comment: do you know anything about  the other question to help me?

Comment: I'm afraid that seems to be slightly out of my scope of interest. However, you should first address the problems there. It was labeled as duplicate (and the duplicate is also a closed one) and it appears to be a self-study question. Obtaining direct answers without effort is discouraged in this forum.

Comment: Could you just tell me how i can compare two models to conclude to which one is better fit?

Comment: 1) That is a broad question 2) post another question with some context, your thoughts & effort to appeal others (there are very expert people specifically on regression) 3) please let's not use this comment thread as if it belongs to us only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101613/discussion-between-pianca-strict-and-gunes).